# *** RuntimeError Exception: ActionView::Helpers::ControllerHelper#response delegated to controller.response, but controller is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm running into an issue when I try to run my api specs for an endpoint. When I run the spec and check the response it says:

```
*** RuntimeError Exception: ActionView::Helpers::ControllerHelper#response delegated to controller.response, but controller is nil: #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007faeb4852b08
```

I have a controller under **controllers/api/v1/catalog_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::CatalogController < ApplicationController
  def search
    ...some stuff here...
    render json: {some_response}
  end
end
```

The matching spec for it is under **spec/controllers/api/v1/catalog_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe Api::V1::CatalogController do
  describe "searching" do
    before(:all) do
      @title = FactoryGirl.create(:title, {name: "Test Title"})
      @author = FactoryGirl.create(:author, last_name: "Smith")
      @edition = FactoryGirl.create(:edition, title: @title, writer_id: @author.id)
    end
    context "#search" do
      it "should return the given titles for a single word search" do
        get :search, {search_terms: {term: 'smith'}}
        expect(response).status.to eql(200)
        return_value.body.should == {titles: [@title]}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change `expect(response).status.to eql(200)` to `expect(response.status).to eql(200)`?

Comment: if I change the get to

    get "/api/v1/catalog/search?search_terms[term]=smith"

then the error becomes "The action '/api/v1/catalog/search?search_terms[term]=smith' could not be found for Api::V1::CatalogController"

Comment: What is in `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: I can't seem to get the formatting to show in comments but here:

namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      namespace :catalog do
        get :search
      end
    end
  end

Comment: when you run rake routes it show:

api_v1_catalog_search GET      /api/v1/catalog/search(.:format)                                             api/v1/catalog#search {:format=>"json"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by removing the line

```
 config.include ActionView::Helpers
```

from my spec_helper.rb config block. I guess it was conflicting. I'm not terribly sure why so any further insight would be awesome.